# angularjs routing with custom id

Tags: angularjs, routes

Hey guys I have a specific question about routing:
Is it possible to use instead of the `:id` in the routing params a custom id, so like passing the id of a `ng-repeat` to the routing? Because when I use the usual id, it is always giving me 1-XX ids, but when I have a list of entries from a Database which gets updated often, then ids will sometimes be the same while one is editing the first and another entry gets added.

Here is a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/QuadroKnoX/bzu0sL2e/